# jQuery AJAX call to Controller action passing array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pass an array of checkbox values from an Ajax form in MVC to a controller action.  Here's my code:

The form (in a modal):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetPrintableProject", "Project", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"}, new { @id = "PrintProjectFormId"))
 {
 <input type="hidden" name="projectId" id="projectId" value="">
```

}

Some jQuery that gets an array of checkbox values:

```
selectedProjects = projectsGrid.$('input[type="checkbox"]').serializeArray();

var projects = [];

$(selectedProjects).each(function (i, field) {
    projects.push(field.value);
});
//the hidden field in a modal I'm using
$('#projectId').val(projects.toString());
```

and the function I'm using to submit:

```
$("#PrintProjectFormId").submit(function (event) {

event.preventDefault();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();

var action = $("#PrintProjectFormId").attr("action");
var dataString = new FormData($("#PrintProjectFormId").get(0));

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: action,
   data: dataString,
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success: function (result) {
            //stuff I'll get to later
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("There was a problem retrieving this project");
        }
        });
    });
```

and then the controller signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetPrintableProject(Guid[] projectId)
```

It works fine if I pass in a single value but if I pass in multiple values the controller just gets 'null'.  Think I'm missing something simple here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: unless you have specific reason to override the defaults of `dataType` `contentType` or `processData` (it doesn't appear that you do) I suggest you keep them the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not changing default option values unless you need.
Create you parameters as a `JSON` object and pass it to `$.ajax`.

From [jQuery API for AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> processData (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Setting this value to false will cause problems when attempting to pass more than one value to the action unless you do the processing within the controller function.

```js
var action = $("#PrintProjectFormId").attr("action");

//fill projects array

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: action,
  data: {
    projectId: $("#PrintProjectFormId").val(),
    "projects": projects
  },
  success: function(result) {
    //stuff I'll get to later
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("There was a problem retrieving this project");
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction.  The controller is actually getting something, but it's just a null guid 00000-000000-00000-00000

Comment: This got me there:

            data: {
                projectId: projects
            }, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 type: "POST",
   url: action, 
   data: {dataString:dataString, dataString1:dataString2, dataString2:dataString2},
```

The format is: index:value

Comment: Passing in data: { dataString: dataString },the controller still sees null.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not passing class but array so your data string should be like:

```
   type: "POST",
   url: action, 
   data:
      [
        "6ccf7071-9b73-4e61-8736-58a842c131d0",
        "9e6c2748-18b5-4a53-a306-eb539c8b7dee",
        "5aa8901a-2c03-42d3-bf06-89f66e3797a4",
        "da5556bf-32aa-4f41-a64a-6e95fa2595c1"
      ],
```

Also try adding `FromBody` in ActionMethod like:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetPrintableProject([FromBody]Guid[] projectId)
```